# Detect who change the model (user input vs controller) angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-watch

I have an input which connected to model. Also, the input has directive which `$watch` the model.

There are 2 ways that the model will change.

1. The user will type in the textbox.
2. The code will change it (no matter what is the reason)

**My question is**

Is there a way to find out who change the model, the user interaction or the code, in the directive?

**Example:**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

})
.directive('dir', function($rootScope){
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $rootScope.logs = [];
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
        // here I need to check if the change was from the UI or from the controller
        
        $rootScope.logs.push('change');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="model" data-dir="" />
  <button data-ng-click="model = 'asd'">Set "model" to defferent value</button>

  {{model}}
  <hr />
  <h3>console <button data-ng-click="$root.logs = []">clear console</button></h3>
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="log in $root.logs track by $index" data-ng-bind="log"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/vufawur/edit?html,js,output

**Update**

**Example2:**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $timeout(function() {
      $scope.model = 'asd';
  }, 3000);
})
.directive('dir', function($rootScope){
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $rootScope.logs = [];
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
        // here I need to check if the change was from the UI or from the controller

        $rootScope.logs.push('change');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="ctrl">
  ...wait until data "return from the server"<br />
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="model" data-dir="" />
  
  {{model}}
  <hr />
  <h3>console <button data-ng-click="$root.logs = []">clear console</button></h3>
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="log in $root.logs track by $index" data-ng-bind="log"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `ext-change` External Change Directive for `ng-model`

Use a `$viewChangeListener` to save the last user input and have the watch handler compare that to discriminate external changes to the model from user input changes to the model.

```
.directive('extChange', function(){
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        var lastUserInput = modelCtrl.$viewValue;
        modelCtrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
            lastUserInput = modelCtrl.$viewValue;
        });
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function watchHandler (value) {
            if (value!==lastUserInput) {
                scope.$eval(attrs.extChange, {$value:value});
            }                
        });
    }
  }
});
```

The example directive saves that last user input. When the watch handler gets a value that is different, it invokes the Angular expression defined by the `ext-change` attribute. The value of the change is exposed as `$value`.

```
<input ng-model="someInput"
       ng-change="userInput=someInput"
       ext-change="extInput=$value">
```

The `ext-change` directive works with the `ng-model` directive and complements the `ng-change` directive.

In this example, the `ext-change` directive only updates the `extInput` variable on external changes to the model. The `ng-change` directive only updates the `userInput` variable for user changes.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6fptjxyh/)

---

The directive can also be used to invoke functions.

```
<input ng-model="someInput"
       ng-change="userEvent(someInput)"
       ext-change="externalEvent($value)">
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `$watch`. You should not use it, you have to not use it, you are going to have trouble if you use `$watch`, you are already in trouble, don't use it.

- [Angular JS - you probably shouldn't use $watch in your controllers.](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/10/title.html)
- [Is it an antipattern to use angular's $watch in a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442183/is-it-an-antipattern-to-use-angulars-watch-in-a-controller)

Use control flow and events. It is possible that you already have a lot of watcher and scope soup, it is not too late, refactor as soon as possible, it is for your best.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

  })
  .directive('dir', function($rootScope) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
        $rootScope.logs = [];

        $scope.modelChange = function(reason) {
          $rootScope.logs.push(reason);
        };

        $scope.modelChangedFromInput = function(model) {
          $scope.modelChange('From input');
        };

        $scope.buttonClick = function() {
          $scope.model = 'asd';
          $scope.modelChange('From button');
        };
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="ctrl">

  <input type="text" data-ng-model="model" data-dir="" data-ng-change="modelChangedFromInput()" />

  <button data-ng-click="buttonClick()">Set "model" to different value</button>

  {{model}}
  <hr />
  <h3>console <button data-ng-click="$root.logs = []">clear console</button>
  </h3>
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="log in $root.logs track by $index" data-ng-bind="log"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is a nice solution for my question BUT the real case is a little bit complex. The model not changed by user interaction but in the controller by data which return from the server (with AJAX) So I can't use this trick. I was updated my question with a better example.